# mantis: how to show custom field in "enter report details" page

Tags: field, mantis

I added a custom field to my Mantis BT installation.  However I can't figure out how to get it to show up on the Enter Report Details page or the edit details page.  (I was able to figure out how to customize the View Issues page and some other places.)

What do I need to do to be able to edit instances of the new field.  Along the same lines, there are existing fields which I would like to hide in the editing views.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the **Manage Custom Fields** page. Click on the custom field and you should see the following options:

- Display When Reporting Issues
- Display When Updating Issues
- Display When Resolving Issues
- Display When Closing Issues
- Required On Report
- Required On Update
- Required On Resolve
- Required On Close

With these options you could control where to display the custom fields.

Comment: I have all those checked but nothing shows up in the "view issues" report nor when reporting a new issue.  Is there some other setting which is preventing this?

Comment: I've tried reinstalling mantis and this problem still persists.

Comment: The answer turns out that I hadn't linked the fields to my project.  This is because the UI is stupid and misleading.  It shows a box with projects in it under the heading "link custom field to project".  To me, this looked like it was showing the projects it was already linked to.  However, you have to highlight them and click the "link custom field" button.  Simple enough once you realize.